# Getting EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION with Java 8 if I load data over 2 GB

Tags: java, javafx, 64-bit

I am using latest Java Runtime 8 and have created an application in JavaFX to load images in a canvas.
If the data size is below 2GB the application runs fine, but if it is even 1 MB over 2GB the following error is logged.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000053def51c, pid=5716, tid=10968

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:    V  [jvm.dll+0x21f51c]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\105064864\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX3DApplication\hs_err_pid5716.log

Compiled method (nm)   51180 1220     n 0       sun.misc.Unsafe::copyMemory (native)
 total in heap  [0x0000000002f4fb10,0x0000000002f4fe90] = 896
 relocation     [0x0000000002f4fc30,0x0000000002f4fc78] = 72
 main code      [0x0000000002f4fc80,0x0000000002f4fe90] = 528

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I have tried several options and nothing works.

I am using Windows 7 and JRE is 8.0

My Java and OS are both 64 bit.

I have tried this on 8GB and 16GB RAMs.

I have set the VM options (-Xmx4g) to allocated 4GB and above but nothing works.

Is there a limit imposed by the graphic card of the machine on the data?
Or is there some other setting apart from the -Xmx4g which we can set to explicitly allow over 2 GB of data loading?

Answer (score 0):

With the magic number being 2GB, the first thing that comes to mind is that somewhere there's an array being initiliazed to hold the whole data. Since in Java an array index must be of type int (Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4), the maximum array length can be Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647). So assuming the data is loaded as a single byte array, we get 2147483647 bytes ~ 2GB as the maximum capacity. Thus, it is possible that by trying to allocate a larger array the application results in the aforementioned exception.

The situation is typically handled by loading data in chunks and not storing everything in the single byte array. However, as far as I've gathered it isn't your code that does the actual physical reading from storage. Perhaps if you mention the use case for the application it would be easier to come up with a higher level solution